# A polynomial vanishes if and only if each homogeneous component vanishes

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Suppose $k$ is an infinite field, $f\in k[x_0,\dots x_n]$, and $x\in k^n$ is a zero of $f$. We can write $f=f_0+\cdots f_r$, where $f_i$ is homogeneous of degree $i$. I am trying to understand a proof given in Perrin's Algebraic Geometry book that $f(x)=0$ implies that $f_i(x)=0$ for each $i$. We have, for any $\lambda\in k$, that $f(\lambda x)=\lambda^rf_r(x)+\cdots +\lambda f_1(x)+f_0(x)=0$. The author then states that "since $k$ is infinite all the values $f_i(x)$ vanish." But this isn't clear to me. Why is this true?

Comment: Treat that equation as a polynomial in $\lambda$: then it has degree $r$ but vanishes at more than $r$ places. Hence it is the zero polynomial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the polynomial $F[y] =f_r(x) y^r +...+  f_1(x) y + f_0(x)$.  Every element of $k$ is a zero of this polynomial and since $k$ is infinite this means this polynomial has infinitely many zeros.  Hence it is the zero polynomial.